# Changing directories in GHC Monad

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Looking at ghc package documentation i found this function:

> `workingDirectoryChanged :: GhcMonad m => m ()`
>
> Inform GHC that the working directory has changed. GHC will flush its cache of module locations, since it may no longer be valid.
>
> Note: Before changing the working directory make sure all threads running in the same session have stopped. If you change the working directory, you should also unload the current program (set targets to empty, followed by load).

I need to run loaded code and compile expressions while changing directories. Is there any way/workaround to this?

One solution i can think of is having separate directory, and setting workdir to that directory whenever interpreter is to be invoked, then restoring old pwd, but i'm not sure if it will work or if this is the best solution.

Comment: Maybe you should use something more high-level, like hint? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint

Comment: "I need to run loaded code and compile expressions while changing directories." - you should provide some context of what you hope to achieve here; the details will determine how you accomplish it.

Comment: @arrowd hint uses GHC Monad, same rules should apply, they could just not be metioned (i guess it's a rare use case)

Comment: @user2407038 I'm embeding haskell runtime into zsh module, which will load and interpret haskell code

Comment: This is very broad; what Haskell code do you wish to embed, and how do you wish to use it from zsh? In other words, is there a minimal example of a situation in which you want to compile `x`, change directories, compile `y`, and this doesn't work because of the aforementioned restriction (where x and y are concrete programs)? (As a potential solution, make `x` and `y` into packages, and have a third module `z` which depends on `x` and `y` via a build system, e.g. cabal).

Comment: @user2407038 1. Create zsh builtins that can: a) load .hs file, b) compile string and store resulting function in a map, c) get function form map and call it (a alredy have b and c implemented using hint, but hint is a little limited)
2. `load somefile.hs; cd somewhere; mkfunc "name" "\args -> funcFromSomeFile $ head args"; callfunc "name" "foo"`

Judging by documentation alone this won't work, i don't want to rely on undefined behaviours if i don't have to.

I am aware that i can create packages, but this is rather cumbersome solution

Comment: If you have a and b, but not yet c, why not write a question which includes: how you've done a and b, how you've attempted to do c, and the overall desired semantics (e.g. should this map be persistent between sessions?). To deal with the pwd issue, you should be able to construct the `Target` explicitly using a fully qualified `FilePath`, which should allow you to bypass the pwd altogether. (Aside: hint is indeed limited; you have have to rewrite things to work with the GHC api directly to get your desired semantics)

Comment: @user2407038 using fully qualified paths is something that will probably let me get away with using GHC api incorrectly. Unless some proper solution to this exists this, or switching directory to some constant ghc work dir and back is the way to go.