# Returning expression from GHC Monad

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I've found this [blog post](https://parenz.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/ghc-api-interpreted-compiled-and-package-modules/), and i was playing a bit with example code.

I've modified first example to look like this:

```
main = defaultErrorHandler defaultFatalMessager defaultFlushOut $ do
runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
    dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
    setSessionDynFlags $ dflags { hscTarget = HscInterpreted
                                , ghcLink   = LinkInMemory
                                }
    setTargets =<< sequence [guessTarget "test.hs" Nothing]
    load LoadAllTargets
    setContext [IIModule $ mkModuleName "Test"]
    !act <- unsafeCoerce <$> compileExpr "print test"  
    setTargets []
    load LoadAllTargets
    liftIO act
```

This happened to work, but this doesn't looks safe - for me this looks like i'm using symbols from module i just unloaded. Will this work in non trivial cases?

Comment: not sure I understand the question... what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: load libraries, compile expression and return it for later use, when those libraries may no longer be loaded (because of [this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.2.1/GHC.html#v:workingDirectoryChanged))

Comment: Do you have an example of it not working? Why do you say you are using symbols from a module? After unloading `test.hs`, you only refer to `act`, which is a value in the *current* Haskell program, not in the interpreted program you previously loaded. Is there a broader context of what you're trying to achieve? (besides this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659935/changing-directories-in-ghc-monad) question, which fails to provide any such context)

Comment: @user2407038 `act` is the compilation of `print test`; presumably `test` comes from the previously-loaded (and unloaded?) `test.hs`. Seems like a perfectly cromulent question and concern to me.

Comment: @user2407038 `test` is just `(123 :: Int)`, so it's trivial. I don't know what kind of code should i load to prove that this is reliable. If you can give me such example i'll try it.

Comment: Test it on whichever code you want to actually interpret (i.e. a "non trivial" case, whatever that may be in your understanding). If you don't have such code, I simply wouldn't worry about it. @DanielWagner It doesn't seem so to me since there is no example showing not-working behaviour, and I don't follow the logic (for the reason I've explained) leading to the conclusion that there exists such an example. As it stands, this question is purely hypothetical (in my opinion) so I don't see how one can answer it (unless one is aware of a counter-example, but I see no reason for it to exist).

Comment: @user2407038 the purpose of this is that it can be possible workaround (not really good, but still) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659935/changing-directories-in-ghc-monad?noredirect=1#comment78284384_45659935) question, namely load file, create and store expressions using this, file, then unload and change directory properly. This looks theoretically correct, but i'm not sure if tinkering with linker won't break referential transparency.